# Print all subsets of a set

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a **recursive** function that receives a number and print all subgroups from 1 to n.
I don't care about the order.

For example if number=3
I need the output:

```
{}
{1}
{2}
{3}
{1,2}
{1,3}
{2,3}
{1,2,3}
```

but my code gives:

```
{1,2,3}
{2,3}
{3}
```

Here is my code, I call the method `subGroups(3);`

```
    public static void subGroups(int num) {
        int[] ar = new int[num];
        subGroups(ar, 1, num);
    }

    private static int[] insertToArr(int num, int[] arr) {
        if (num == 0)
            return arr;
        arr[num - 1] = num;
        return insertToArr(num - 1, arr);
    }

    private static void subGroups(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (end <= 0 || start > arr.length)
            return;
        else if (start > end)
            subGroups(arr, start, end - 1);
        else {
            if (start != 0) {
                System.out.print("{");

                printAll(start, end);
                System.out.println("}");
            }
            subGroups(arr, start + 1, end);
        }

    }

    // prints all in in one line recursive
    private static void printAll(int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            System.out.print(start + ",");
            printAll(start + 1, end);
        } else {
            System.out.print(start);
        }

    }
```

How do I get the requested result?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work, see how this may be ported to arrays.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.Collections.emptySet;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Main {
    public static void powerset(int n) {
        System.out.println(
                powerset(IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).boxed().collect(toList()))
        );
    }

    public static Set<Set<Integer>> powerset(List<Integer> set) {
        if (set.isEmpty()) {
            Set<Set<Integer>> result = new HashSet();
            result.add(emptySet());
            return result ;
        } else {
            Integer element = set.remove(0);
            Set<Set<Integer>> pSetN_1 = powerset(set);

            Set<Set<Integer>> pSet_N= new HashSet();
            pSet_N.addAll(pSetN_1);

            for (Set<Integer> s : pSetN_1) {
                Set<Integer> ss = new HashSet(s);
                ss.add(element);
                pSet_N.add(ss);
            }
            return pSet_N;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        powerset(3); // [[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
    }
}
```

By the way, you are calculating a power set, a set of all subsets (not groups) of a set

Comment: Please explain the problem with the OP's code and especially your answer. Else it is not helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If `(start > end)` is true, then it will be true of the recursive call `subGroups(arr, start, end-1)` as well, and the recursion will continue along this path until `end` is too small.

So something here needs to change.  Consider that nowhere do you ever reset either `start` or `end`.

Answer (score 0):

A few hints, and a code skeleton below: `arr` should be used as an accumulator for the subset being found. It has initial size=0, and the size is incremented whenever an element is added to the current subset.

The initial call should be:

```
int[] arr = new int[0];
subGroups(arr, 1, num);
```

since at this point, you have selected 0 elements and you still need to select a subset of elements `{1,...,num}`.

The function `subGroups` should be:

```
/*
 * generates all subsets of set {start,...,end} , union "arr"
 */
private static void subGroups(int[] arr, int start, int end) {
  //terminal condition: print the array
  if (start>end) {
    print(arr);
  }
  else {
    //here we have 2 cases: either element "start" is part of the subset, or it isn't

    // case 1: "start" is not part of the subset
    // so "arr" is unchanged
    subGroups(arr, start+1, end);

    // case 2: "start" is part of the subset
    // TODO: create another array, containing all elements of "arr", and "start"
    int[] arrWithStart=copyAndInsert(arr, start);
    subGroups(arrWithStart, start+1, end);
  }
}

private static void print(int[] arr) {
  // TODO code here
}

/*
 * copy and insert:
 * it should create a new array, with length=arr.length+1,
 * containing all elements of array "arr", and also "element"
 */
static int[] copyAndInsert(int[] arr, int element) {
  // TODO code here
}
```